# White line through optionmenu

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I get a [weird line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mAJY.jpg) through my optionmenu and I have no idea why. Any tips? Just test code, but I have no idea where that line comes from. I've tried changing the size of the menu to fix it and tried to find the error but I just can't find it. It's not "game-breaking" but it's still kinda annoying that I can't get rid of it.

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()
root.state("zoomed")
root.title("XP-dot GUI")
root.configure(background='black')

mainframe = Frame(root, width=50)
mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

buttonframe = Frame(root)
buttonframe.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=(N,W))
buttonframe.configure(background='blue')

tkvar = StringVar(root)
tkvar.set('1 row')
choices = ['1 row','2 rows','Still frame','Animation', 'diy']
r=0
c=0

theLabel = Label(root, text="")
theLabel.grid(row=r,column=c)

dropDown = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
Label(mainframe, text="Options").grid(row=r, column=c)
dropDown.grid(row=r, column=c+1, sticky=(W,E))
dropDown.config(width=14)

def preview():
    print ("value is", tkvar.get())
button = Button(buttonframe, text="Preview", command=preview)
button.grid(row=5,column=0)

def random():
    print ("value is", tkvar.get())
button = Button(buttonframe, text="Randomize", command=random)
button.grid(row=5,column=1)

def update():
    print ("value is", tkvar.get())
button = Button(buttonframe, text="Update", command=update)
button.grid(row=5,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "line" is `theLabel`. Both it and `mainframe` have been put in row 0, column 0 of the root window.

You can see this more clearly if you give `theLabel` some text. Because it doesn't have any text, it appears as a fairly small rectangle. Because it was added after `mainframe` was added to root, it appears on top of `mainframe`.